# login to embedded-linux device without password via ssh or serial port from Ubuntu side

Tags: shell, ssh, passwords, embedded-linux, root

I want to connect to my embedded-linux device but I have any password from it and can not connect to console of this! (i dont have any screen and lcd)
I want to login to my embedded-linux device with Ubuntu on my Laptop via ssh or serial port.
please help me.

Comment: You should maybe mention what embedded device you want to connect to, then you should be able to find the default password. If that does not work you can always wipe it clean and reinstall a new image of which the password is known.

Comment: Can you see any output on serial port?